# C# Monitor.Enter not lock if Object lies within another Object

Tags: c#, object, locking

I thought Monitor.Enter works on references to objects as long as the reference to the object or the object itself does not change.

So here is my simple case, I have a class called QueueManager which has an Queue in it. I'm using this object Queue to lock using Monitor.Lock before manipulating the queue. I tried a simple test of calling Monitor.Lock on the queue object and it fails. Any idea why?

```
public class QueueManager
{
    private List<ConversionJob> _jobQueue = new List<ConversionJob>();

    public QueueManager()
    {
    }

    public List<ConversionJob> Queue
    { get { return _jobQueue; } }
}

public class Main
{
    private QueueManager qMgr = new QueueManager();

    public Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Monitor.Enter(qMgr.Queue);
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(qMgr.Queue);
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't DEADLOCK!! I can't understand why it doesn't deadlock. I tried this because I suspected the locks were being taken so I put this test code in and I'm surprised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monitors are *re-entrant* - one thread can own a monitor multiple times. The monitor is only unlocked (available for another thread to acquire it) when `Exit` has been called the same number of times as `Enter`.

From the docs for [`Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.exit.aspx):

> The calling thread must own the lock on the obj parameter. If the calling thread owns the lock on the specified object, and has made an equal number of Exit and Enter calls for the object, then the lock is released. If the calling thread has not invoked Exit as many times as Enter, the lock is not released.

Comment: Thanks, then suppose instead of throwing an exception a real exception is thrown I was using this code to Release the lock:

`Monitor.TryEnter(_qMgr.Queue, 1); // Try to get the lock
Monitor.Exit(_qMgr.Queue); // Release the lock`

This won't work in this case. So how do I knon if the lock was taken?

Comment: @user2280961: Adding code in comments is rarely a good idea. But basically you should pretty much *always* use the `lock` statement instead of manually calling `Enter` and `Exit`. Note that `Monitor.TryEnter` returns a `bool` (or accepts an `out` parameter) to indicate success or failure.

Comment: yes but TryEnter will ALWAYS take the lock since it's recursive reentrant. so it doesn't help my case, right?

Comment: @user2280961: It might help if you tell us what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sure, in the main thread there could be an exception thrown. In the Catch statement I want to check of the lock was taken prior to the exception and not released and if so then release it. How can I accomplish this without using the reference variable in Monitor.Enter?

Comment: @rboy - ask your questions in the Question, not in a comment-trail.

Comment: okay thanks both of you - will research some more before posting this question

Comment: @rboy: And post it as a *new* question... this question is answered, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

> This doesn't DEADLOCK!!

That is because both calls to `Enter()` are made from the same thread. Monitor is recursive-reentrant.